# wildcard subdomains in development with passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, subdomain, passenger

It really bites having to add an alias every time you need a subdomain on your development machine. Is there a way to configure passenger to use wildcards so that i can access randomsubdomain.mysite.local ?

Answer (score 4):

This is not a passenger problem. It depends on which server you're using:

**nginx**:

```
server {
    # …
    server_name www.yourdomain.com *.yourdomain.com;
    # …
}
```

**apache**:

```
<VirtualHost …>
    # …
    ServerName www.yourdomain.com
    ServerAlias *.yourdomain.com
    # …
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to have wildcard subdomains you need to have a DNS server running on your local machine. Below are some articles that got it working for me:

1. [Setup bind](http://www.macshadows.com/kb/index.php?title=How_To:_Enable_BIND_-_Mac_OS_X's_Built-in_DNS_Server) (only step 1 in this article)
2. [Configure DNS server](http://groups.drupal.org/node/16862#osx) (Replace 'vmdev' with 'local' in this article)
3. add `*.app.local` in passenger pref pane 'Aliases' for each app